# PMD/Checkstyle - Force usage of Constant in Annotation-Value

Tags: java, annotations, checkstyle, pmd, static-code-analysis

I have a java annotation `@Foo(value = "MyValueA")`. As it can only use a couple of values, I decided to put them as constants into a class. So a user can use `@Foo(value = MyValues.A)` instead.

How can I make PMD or Checkstyle enforce the usage of this constants, instead of raw Strings?

Comment: Use an `enum`..

Comment: @Foo(...) is from an external library. I can not change the type of its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PMD, you can create [your own ruleset](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.18.0/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html) to define [a custom rule using an XPath expression](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.18.0/pmd_userdocs_extending_writing_xpath_rules.html#creating-a-new-rule-definition) to match for cases where this annotation's value is set to a literal string:

```xml
//NormalAnnotation[@AnnotationName = 'Foo']//MemberValuePair[@Image = 'value']/MemberValue//Literal
```